# Vim errorformat for jshint (with example)

Tags: vim, errorformat

I am trying to write efm for this:

```
file: app/assets/javascripts/topbar.js
  line 17, col 3, Missing semicolon.
  line 19, col 19, 'is_mobile' was used before it was defined.
  line 21, col 1965, Expected '{' and instead saw 'check'.
  line 25, col 18, 'onScroll' was used before it was defined.
file: app/assets/javascripts/trends.js
  line 2, col 55, Missing semicolon.
  line 6, col 27, 'trendTypeSelected' was used before it was defined.
  line 7, col 32, Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
JSHint check failed
```

but I think I am missing the concept of file on separate line. Can someone help me out with 
this?

This is what I have so far and it does not work:

```
%-Pfile:\ %f,line\ %l\,\ col\ %c\,\ %m
```

Thanks!

Solution:

```
set efm=%-Pfile:\ %f,%*[\ ]line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %m,%-Q,%-GJSHint\ check\ failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim provides `%P`, which pushes the parsed file (`%f`) onto the stack, see `:help errorformat-separate-filename`.

So for your error output, it would be something like `%+Pfile: %f,...`

Comment: I know, but for some reason it does not work. Let me edit the question with what I have now.

Comment: Ok I guess I need to read that manual. Nevermind :-) At least I tried :-D

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much experience with errorformats, neither. It's best to have a look at the existing compiler plugins. Good luck!